# GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ConnectException cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8088: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, guzzle6, laradock

I'm using `laradock` and I can access the page in browser `http://localhost:8088/api/getakicks/get` without any problems.

But when I try to access it in controller I'm getting this error:

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ConnectException cURL error 7: Failed to
>   connect to localhost port 8088: Connection refused

The code I use:

```
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

  // Set various headers on a request
  $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8088/api/getakicks/get');
```

Answer (score 9):

Get IP address on MAC, click on wifi icon -> Open Network Preferences -> then copy the IP address 192.168.100.41 (own unique IP) and replace with xxx in below code

```
$client->request('GET', 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:8088/api/getakicks/get');
```

Comment: yes I  did change it and it is working well.

Answer (score 1):

changed the IP address from localhost:8088 to windows IP address 192.168.x.x:8088.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I get cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: 118.238.x.x  I'm on Mac

Comment: Replace x with number, for example 192.168.1.24

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei I did in the first place - just didn't wanna flash my IP out :)